# How to update Nuxt.js to the latest version

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt.js 1.2 in my project, but I want to update it to latest version. How to do it? What needs to be considered when updating the version?

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/release-notes/#migration-guide-for-2-0-0

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/upgrading

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply run:  `yarn upgrade nuxt@^2.3.2`

As stated [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/release-notes/):

> Please note that for upgrading Nuxt.js just changing version inside
>   `package.json` is not enough. Please use yarn upgrade or npm upgrade so
>   that the final directory structure of `node_modules` will be correct. In
>   case of problems clean up `node_modules` and
>   `yarn.lock/package-lock.json`.

Comment: another simple way: `yarn upgrade nuxt --latest`

Comment: obviously for npm users, just change yarn -> npm

Comment: getting this error:

Usage Error: Couldn't find a script named "upgrade".

$ yarn run [--inspect] [--inspect-brk] [-T,--top-level] [-B,--binaries-only] [--require #0] <scriptName> ...